# Can I restrict a protocol to one type of class?

Tags: swift, uiview, protocols

I am writing some transitioning protocols, and I would like them to only be available to UIView classes:

```
public protocol TransitioningView where Self: UIView
{
    func transitionDelay(pushFrom: UIView?) -> TimeInterval?
    func transitionDuration(popTo: UIView?) -> TimeInterval
    func transitionDuration(pushFrom: UIView?) -> TimeInterval
    func animateTransition(popTo: UIView?   , finished: ((Bool) -> Void)?)
    func animateTransition(pushFrom: UIView?, finished: ((Bool) -> Void)?)
}
```

But this doesn't seem quite right. The compiler does not consider a UIView that has been cast to a TransitioningView as being a UIView.

example:

```
let x = myController.view as? TransitioningView
x.animateTransition(popTo: nil, finished: nil) // OK
x.backgroundColor = .clear // NOPE
```

This is a bit annoying because sometimes I want to pass around a view that I have confirmed to be a TransitioningView. Is there a better pattern?

Comment: I guess, you can add some property to `TransitioningView` protocol, which would be like `var view: UIView { return self as UIView}`, and use it like x.view.backgroundColor, or just access `myController.view`

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `public protocol TransitioningView where Self: UIView`, you are defining that the `TransitioningView` requires an inheritance from `UIView`, but i can't see any implementation of `TransitioningView` into `UIView`.

I'll give you two examples on how you can do this.

First you can create a default implementation of the protocol:

```
extension TransitioningView {

    public func transitionDelay(pushFrom: UIView?) -> TimeInterval? {
        return 1
    }

    public func transitionDuration(popTo: UIView?) -> TimeInterval {
        return 1
    }

    public func transitionDuration(pushFrom: UIView?) -> TimeInterval {
        return 1
    }

    public func animateTransition(popTo: UIView?, finished: ((Bool) -> Void)?) {

    }

    public func animateTransition(pushFrom: UIView?, finished: ((Bool) -> Void)?) {

    }
}
```

This example will make every object that inherits from `UIView` conform to `TransitioningView`, this might be a over-kill depending on how much you utilize the `TransitioningView` functionality:

```
extension UIView: TransitioningView {}
```

The last example will implement `TransitioningView` directly in the custom class:

```
class MyCustomView: UIView, TransitioningView {}
class MyCustomLabel: UILabel, TransitioningView {}
```

Independent of how you implement it they both use the same default implementation in the `extension TransitioningView`. This behavior can be "overridden" in the either an extension or in the class itself.

```
extension TransitioningView where Self: UITextField {

    public func animateTransition(pushFrom: UIView?, finished: ((Bool) -> Void)?) {
        // Some custom transition
    }
}
```

or

```
class MyCustomView: UIView, TransitioningView {

    func transitionDuration(popTo: UIView?) -> TimeInterval {
        return 2
    }
}
```

For further reference:

[Extensions - The Swift Programming Language (Swift 4)](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH24-ID151)

[Protocols - The Swift Programming Language (Swift 4)](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID267)

Comment: This is an interesting idea for changing pattern for defining these transitions, but I don't actually want *every* view to conform the protocol. I just want to make sure that some random object cannot conform to it.

Comment: By using the constraint you have defined yourself you are securing that the `TransitioningView` protocol can't be used on objects that's not descendants of `UIView`. I'm not sure if i understand what you're asking since you already got an answer to question in the title.